# Copy current record to another table with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with php and mysql, I want to copy the current record a user is inserting into another table I tried INSERT INTO / SELECT, it works but when I refresh the page where people record something all records copy to the another table over and over.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM supervisores";
$query          = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$row            = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$id    = $row[0];
$nombre    = $row[1];




$sql = "INSERT INTO`prueba` (`nombre`) SELECT (nombre) FROM 
metlab.supervisores WHERE id ='$id'";
$sql    =   mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

I just want to copy the current record the user is typing id of both tables are AI

Thanks in advance

Comment: mysql is deprecated start using mysqli with prepared statements this is completely unsecure

Comment: avoid doing the copying in your view. Instead, outsource the copying part to another route, like yoursite.com/dothecopy. After successful insert etc, redirect to the actual view. now you can refresh the view without copying again

Comment: yeah i know but security its not important in this case its just for a homework, I was thinking if it would be a better idea to do this with a trigger

Comment: If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later? I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."* or *"Ignore the security risk..."*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

`$sql = "INSERT INTO prueba (nombre) VALUES ($nombre) WHERE id = '$id'";`

1)use mysqli instead of mysql

2) instead of $row[0] use $row[nombre_ID]  (if thats what its called)

3) do the same for $row[1] to like $row[nombre]

4) change mysql_fetch_row($query) to mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)

Comment: i editted the answer check agian and see if that works. And if you can, tell me what error u are getting from the die error

Comment: 2 downvoters without giving a reason for the downvote?

Comment: not its not working Im trying to insert an existing record(the current one) to another table

Comment: Ill give you the correct answer I dont know why people is giving downvote :/

Comment: idk either. But did my editted answer work for you atleast?

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).